# Linear Algebra done Right 7.1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

7.1 Proposition: Every eigenvalue of a self-adjoint operator is real.

Proof: Suppose $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on $V$. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$, and $v$ a non-zero vector in $V$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$  Then 
\begin{align}
\lambda \|v\|^2 &= \langle \lambda v, v\rangle\\
&= \langle Tv, v\rangle\\
&= \langle v, Tv\rangle
\end{align}

I don't understand that last step. how come $\langle Tv, v\rangle = \langle v, Tv\rangle$ and not its conjugate?

Comment: $\langle Tv, u \rangle = \langle v, T^*u \rangle$ for any operator $T$ and any vectors $v,u$ — this is the definition of $T^*$. If $T$ is self-adjoint, $T^* = T$.

Comment: @lisyarus this answers my questtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of not leaving the question unanswered,

The definition of the *adjoint* $T^*: W \rightarrow V$ of an operator $T:V \rightarrow W$ is the relation

$$\forall v\in V, w \in W : \, \langle Tv,w \rangle_W = \langle v, T^*w\rangle_V$$

Here, $V$ and $W$ are inner-product spaces (real, complex, Hermitian or Hilbert - choose your favorite), while $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_V$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_W$ denote the inner product in $V$ and $W$, respectively.

Next, the definition of *self-adjoint* operator $T : V \rightarrow V$ is just $T = T^*$. In this case, for any $v \in V$, we get

$$\langle Tv, v\rangle = \langle v, T^*v\rangle = \langle v, Tv \rangle$$